# how to calculate percentage and format table

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table looks like:

```
c_id  soap_spend  towel_spend  year_spend cluster
c1     1           2              3          1
c2     2           4              6          2
c3     1           2              3          2
c4     3           2              5          1
```

I want to return two tables.

table 1:

```
                     cluster_1          cluster_2
    % soap_spend     a = (1+3)/(3+5)   c= (2+1)/(6+3) -- soap_spend.sum/year_spend.sum 
    % towel_spend    b = (2+2)/(3+5)   d= (2+4)/(6+3) -- towel_spend.sum/year_spend.sum
```

table 2:

```
    use results from table 1
                            cluster_1          cluster_2
        % soap_spend     a/mean(soap_spend)   c/mean(towel_spend)
        % towel_spend    b/mean(soap_spend)  d/mean(towel_spend)
```

my code:

```
    cols = ['soap_spend', 'towel_spend']
    df.groupby('cluster').apply(df[col].sum()/df['year_spend'].sum()
```

any suggestions on hwo to fix the code?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to group by cluster, it's enough to sum with loc operations like this:

```
numerator = df['soap_spend'].loc[df['cluster'] == val].sum()
denominator = df['year_spend'].loc[df['cluster'] == val].sum()
```

The full code would be like this:

```
for val in df.cluster.unique():
     soap_numerator = df['soap_spend'].loc[df['cluster'] == val].sum()
     denominator = df['year_spend'].loc[df['cluster'] == val].sum()

     towel_numerator = df['towel_spend'].loc[df['cluster'] == val].sum()

     soap_spend = soap_numerator / denominator
     towel_spend = towel_numerator / denominator
     col = [soap_spend,towel_spend]
     df_results.insert(int(val),'cluster_{}'.format(int(val)),col)
  
df_results = df_results[['cluster_1','cluster_2']]
```

For the table 2 you should apply that:

```
table_2 = table_1.copy()
for row in range(table_2.shape[0]):
  for col in table_2.columns:
    table_2[col].iloc[row] = table_2[col][row] / table_2.iloc[row].mean()
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the `.sum()` method or the `np.sum` function instead of `sum`. It should be faster and will handle missing data in a way that's in line with how pandas usually works.

Comment: You are right @creanion, thank you. I've already applied the changes.